# Interval at which the integral value may lie between

Tags: calculus

> Let = $f:R \rightarrow R$ be defined as $f(x)=e^{-x} \sin x$. If $F:[0,1] \rightarrow R$ is a differentiable function such that $F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} f(t) d t$ then the value of $\int_{0}^{1}\left(F^{\prime}(x)+f(x)\right) e^{x} d x$ lies in the interval
> (A) $\left[\frac{327}{360}, \frac{329}{360}\right]$
> (B) $\left[\frac{330}{360}, \frac{331}{360}\right]$
> (C) $\left[\frac{331}{360}, \frac{334}{360}\right]$
> (D) $\left[\frac{335}{360}, \frac{336}{360}\right]$.             My approach was to take the integral to be $2f(x)e^x$ now for finding the optimum range at which the integral may lie i tried to bound the integrand with $cos\theta$ max and minimum value in that limit of integration cos1 and cos0 ,but it doesnt leads to the closest range at which options are pointing out , is there a better way to get the closest range at which it may lie ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that $F'=f$, but notice that $2f(x)e^x=2e^xe^{-x}\sin x=2\sin x$, so that the integral is just $2\int_0^1 \sin x\,dx=2(\cos 0 - \cos 1)$.

You will have to approximately calculate $\cos(1)$, but $1$ rad is pretty close to $60^\circ$, so it shouldn't be a problem.